# 'Editors' picks' Vs. 'Editor's picks'

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

Some websites use **Editors' picks** while others use **Editor's picks** .

Which one of these is correct?

Is **Editors' picks** correct when the publication have more than one editor?

Comment: I would say "Editors' Picks" is incorrect if the picks are made by only one editor.  But both are correct when picks are made by two or more editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, depends on how many editors there are.

If you have one Editor, her pick is the **Editor's** pick. (The pick of the Editor.)

If you have three, their pick is the **Editors'** pick. (The pick of the Editors.)

Comment: Please avoid answering questions that are either better asked on ELL / a basic English website or duplicates (here, mysteriously, both).